# Why re-constructing view hierarchy is affordable in declarative UI frameworks like Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, imperative-programming, declarative-programming

I am reading Flutter's official documentation on state management and in [this page](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/declarative) it says:

> For example, in Flutter it’s okay to rebuild parts of your UI from scratch instead of modifying it. Flutter is fast enough to do that, even on every frame if needed.

As an Android developer, it is true in most cases that constructing a `View` is expensive and should be avoided. So I am wondering why re-constructing view hierarchy is affordable in Flutter.

Comparing the class declarations of Android's `View` and Flutter's `Widget`, the Android View has much more fields and do a lot of works in the constructor, so I guess one reason is that creating a new class instance in Flutter is cheaper than that in Android. But why Android (as an imperative framework) needs such a complex `View` class to drive the UI than Flutter (as a declarative framework)? What's the common difference between the UI rendering mechanisms of imperative UI and declarative UI?

Comment: check https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-layer-cake-widgets-elements-renderobjects-7644c3142401

Answer (score 0):

It's not a difference between declarative and imperative models, per se.  It's that Android `View`s are expensive to create.  You're right on the mark when you say "the Android View has much more fields and do a lot of works in the constructor" - this is exactly the problem.  Flutter's `Widget`s are very lightweight, containing just enough information to allow the system to figure out what the Element tree should look like.  The `Element`s are the heavier-weight objects with state that's potentially expensive to recreate (including `RenderObject`s), and those are created only once (for each Widget location in the Widget tree).  After that, they're just updated with new information when there's a change in the Widget tree rather than being recreated from scratch.

Here are a couple articles with some more information that you might find helpful:

- https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-what-are-widgets-renderobjects-and-elements-630a57d05208
- https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-layer-cake-widgets-elements-renderobjects-7644c3142401